# C Tic Tac Toe Program - Crashing Out During Function Calling in Main

Tags: c

`Hi All, apologies in advance I am very new to this altogether.  I am learning C right now and one of the beginner exercises is to write a tic tac toe program.  I have written a few functions for this that I am trying to get to work together and currently I am hitting a point where the program crashes when I am attempting some testing in the main function.  I have posted the code below.  Sorry it is a mess Im sure.  Most of it is commented out presently.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//GLOBAL WORKSPACE//
char playerOneMarkX = 'X'; //output of 'X' for player 1 marking board
char playerTwoMarkO = 'O';
char playerOneInput; //input from scanf for player 1
char playerTwoInput;
char boardSpaces[10] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' } ;//define the array that will house the spaces of the board
bool playerOneWins;


    //declare function to draw board
    //it will pull directly from the values stored in the array boardSpaces
    //it is marked as void type and void for arguments because it will not require any arguments to be invoked in main
    void drawBoard(void)
    {
    system("clear"); //This is the syntax to clear the screen so the board can be re-drawn in between changes
    printf("\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\nPlayer 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)\n\n");

    printf("       |       |       \n");
    printf("   %c   |   %c   |   %c   \n", boardSpaces[1], boardSpaces[2] , boardSpaces[3]);
    printf("_______|_______|_______\n");
    printf("       |       |       \n");
    printf("   %c   |   %c   |   %c   \n", boardSpaces[4], boardSpaces[5], boardSpaces[6]);
    printf("_______|_______|_______\n");
    printf("       |       |       \n");
    printf("   %c   |   %c   |   %c   \n", boardSpaces[7], boardSpaces[8], boardSpaces[9]);
    printf("       |       |       \n");

    //return 0;
    }


    //declare function to mark the board based on player input
    //X for player 1, O for player 2
    //the for loop iterates through the elements of the boardSpaces array
    //if the player input is the same as one of the elements it will replace the value stored with an X
    void p1markBoard(void)
    {
        char loop; //variable to loop through array

        for (loop = 0; loop <=10; loop++ ){
                if ( boardSpaces[loop] == playerOneInput){
                boardSpaces[loop] = playerOneMarkX;
                }
                //printf("\n%c", boardSpaces[loop]);//FORTESTINGONLY - prints the array iteration
        }
                //printf("\nValue of element 5: %c", spaces[5]);//FORTESTINGONLY
                                                                //testing the value of element 5 outside of the loop
                                                                // so if the player input is 5, this will report an X
    }


    /*
    void checkForWin(void)
    {
        if (boardSpaces[1]&&boardSpaces[2]&&boardSpaces[3]=='X')
            playerOneWins = true;
            printf("\nPlayer One Wins!!!");


    }
    */
    void p1Turn (void)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a value between 1-9 to choose the corresponding space:");//output to terminal to request input from user to select a space
        scanf("%c", &playerOneInput);//stores entered value from user into variable playerOneInput
        //printf("\nYou entered: %c", playerOneInput);//prints the playerAnswer. FORTESTINGONLY

        return playerOneInput;
    }


int main()
{

    /*
    int movement;
    for( movement = 0 ; playerOneWins = true ; movement++){

        drawBoard();

        printf("\nEnter a value between 1-9 to choose the corresponding space:");//output to terminal to request input from user to select a space
        scanf("%c", &playerOneInput);//stores entered value from user into variable playerOneInput
        //printf("\nYou entered: %c", playerOneInput);//prints the playerAnswer. FORTESTINGONLY

        markBoard();

        //checkForWin();

        system("clear");
    }
*/

drawBoard();
p1Turn();
p1markBoard();
drawBoard();
p1Turn();
p1markBoard();
drawBoard();

    //return 0;
}`
```

I am right now just trying to test the functions in main to get them flowing before developing further.  Right now the program is exiting out after the second call to the drawBoard function.  I'm trying to figure out why this is happening so I can continue testing the functions and then develop functions for player 2, etc.`

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: As a possible hint, the loop `for (loop = 0; loop <=10; loop++ )` will iterate over *eleven* elements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , thank you for the quick replies.  I will review these for sure. I appreciate any help!!

Comment: @omek You're indexing past the bounds of your arrays.  The valid indices for a 10-element array are 0 through 9.  Your loops run from 0 to 10.  10 is an invalid index.  My advice to beginners is:  Learn to count.  If you can't count, you can't use arrays.

Comment: Also, when just compiling the code, the compiler was sending back a lot of warnings (e.g. using a character variable as an index, returning a value for a function defining a "void" return, and so forth).  So along with the bounds issues noted, pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `p1Turn()` for the third time, you will see that it works. This behavior is likely due to the way the `%c` specifier works in the `scanf` function: It collects whitespace characters, including the Enter key, so it does not behave as expected on the second call.

I think the simplest solution is to add a space before `%c` like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &playerOneInput);
```

This problem is also well described here: [Using scanf() function two times: works in one case but not in other case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096915/using-scanf-function-two-times-works-in-one-case-but-not-in-other-case).

Also, the `p1Turn()` function is declared as a `void` function, so it shouldn't return a value.

Comment: Thank you for this!  The addition of the space before the %c is allowing multiple calls to the function now.  I will review the link you provided as well to better understand why this occurs.